# XE2 XML Attribute can't convert to double

Tags: xml, type-conversion, c++builder-xe2

I have a XML node with attributes like this:

```
<pad name="E" x="2.5" y="7" drill="1.3"/>
```

When I assign the `Attributes["x"]` into a double I get the result 25, not 2.5 but without any complaints or errors.

To get a correct conversion I first have to assign the attribute to a string, replace the decimal '.' to a decimal ',' and then convert the string to a double. It is clearly that the `Attribute["x"]` can't convert but it doesn't say anything! (bug?!?)

Here is the code with faulty conversion:

```
double x = XMLNode->Attributes["x"];
```

This gives a faulty x of 25 instead of 2.5 and here is my work around:

```
String sd = XMLNode->Attributes["x"];
if (sd.Pos(".")) sd[sd.Pos(".")] = ',';
double x = sd.ToDouble();
```

This gives the correct value in x (2.5)

There MUST be a more simple way to do this!

// Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML attributes are arbitrary string values if you are not using an XSD to coherce the data, such as with the IDE's XML Data Binding wizard.  The `Attributes[]` property returns an `OleVariant`, which in this case is going to contain a `System::String` in it.  When a `System::String` is converted to a `double` using the `OleVariant`'s `double` conversion operator or the `String::ToDouble()` method, the conversion uses the global `SysUtils::DecimalSeparator` variable, which is initialized using your PC's locale settings, which are clearly using the `,` character as a decimal separator instead of the `.` character.  XML has no way of knowing that locale setting.

Since you are using a modern version of C++Builder, you can use the overloaded version of the `StrToFloat()` function that lets you pass in a `TFormatSettings` record as input.  You can then specific `.` as the `TFormatSettings::DecimalSeparator` to use for the conversion, eg:

```
TFormatSettings fmt = TFormatSettings::Create();
fmt.DecimalSeparator = '.';
double x = StrToFloat(XMLNode->Attributes["x"], fmt);
```